# Add a carriage return in HTML

Tags: html, grails

I need to send an email every day (in html) with the people registered in my page. Im using Grails plugin "mail" to send the email. it is sent without problems. But, the mail is sent without carriage return, and obviously it results in an almost unreadable mail. This is the code:

```
ArrayList users=User.findAllByRegistradaBetween(date-1,date)
String results="\r\n"
for (int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
results = results+users[i].mail+"\r\n"
mailService.sendMail {

    to  'destinationmail@gmail.com'
    from "sendermail@gmail.com"
    subject "A subject"
    html '<label>Users registered today: '+results+'</label></br>'
    }
```

I tried with \r\n but doesn't works, as I suspected, in HTML. How can I get something like that?:

User1@mail.com

User2@mail.com

User3@mail.com

etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Tried with <br/> or <p></p>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using an HTML line break instead `<br />`, the email is HTML so this should work just fine.

`results = results+users[i].mail+"<br />"`

Comment: Yeah, sure, i tried before but said that i must wait 4 minutes. There is your vote :)